# DateTime parser format in java 8

Tags: java, datetime-format

I am trying to parse a datetimeStamp as below but I am not able to find the correct parser for it. Can someone advise how can I parse such dates:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
          int DAYS = 30;
         String date ="2021-04-23T12:09:56.123-07:00";
            DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter
      .ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS±hh:mm");
        
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        System.out.println("Local Date" + localDateTime);
      LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
      if (localDateTime.isBefore(now) && localDateTime.isAfter(now.plusDays(DAYS)))
        {
             System.out.println("Date is incorrect");
        }else{
             System.out.println("Success");
        }
     }
}
```

Below is also a bit of additional detail:
Must be expressed in ISO 8601 extended format as one of the following - YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[ .sss ]Z, YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[ .sss ]±hh:mm . Where [ .sss ] is optional and can be 1 to 3 digits. Must be a value no more than 30 days in the future. Mastercard recommends using a value of (Current Time + 30 minutes). Max length - 29. Type - String.
example: "2015-07-04T12:09:56.123-07:00"

Please help me with the correct formatter for the day specified.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code?

Comment: the  arg in the ofPattern() in the code                                                                      DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter
      .ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS±hh:mm");

Comment: `±hh:mm` should probably be `Z`

Comment: You cannot parse the `String` like this. You need a different pattern (or none at all) and a different class: `OffsetDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime` (which isn't able to read and store information about an offset).

Comment: Thanks @Lino I tried that didn't work

Comment: "As one of the following" - this means that you are trying to parse is not always in the same format? Btw, I would try it with this yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of this wrong pattern (and the `DateTimeFormatter`) at all and use an `OffsetDateTime` instead of a `LocalDateTime` which isn't able to store information about an offset.

This is a conversion of your code (slightly adjusted and commented):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "2021-04-23T12:09:56.123-07:00";
    
    /*
     * no DateTimeFormatter needed due to default format of the String
     */
    
    // use an OffsetDateTime to parse a String with an offset
    OffsetDateTime odtParsed = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);
    // print it
    System.out.println("Parsed OffsetDateTime is " + odtParsed);
    // take the current instant as an OffsetDateTime at an offset of -7 hours
    OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7));
    
    // run your check and get a success
    if (odtParsed.isBefore(now) && odtParsed.isAfter(now.plusDays(DAYS))) {
        System.out.println("Date is incorrect");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
}
```

It prints

```
Parsed OffsetDateTime is 2021-04-23T12:09:56.123-07:00
Success
```

**Hint:** This will fail for differently formatted `String`s. If the formattings only differ a little, you might be able to create a `DateTimeFormatter` (via a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`) that can handle optional parts and so on.

## Edit

If only the millis of day are optional and the format of the offset always consists of a plus or minus followed by two digits for hours, a colon and two digits for minutes, the following example might be showing a sufficient way of making it **generic**:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "2021-04-23T12:09:56.123-07:00";
    String date1 = "2021-04-23T12:09:56.123+02:00";
    String date2 = "2021-04-23T12:09:56.123+00:00";
    String date3 = "2021-04-23T12:09:56-07:00";
    String date4 = "2021-04-23T12:09:56+02:00";
    String date5 = "2021-04-23T12:09:56+00:00";
    
    // DateTimeFormatter using optional millis of second
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]xxx");
    
    // use an OffsetDateTime to parse a String with an offset
    OffsetDateTime odtParsed = OffsetDateTime.parse(date, dtf);
    OffsetDateTime odtParsed1 = OffsetDateTime.parse(date1, dtf);
    OffsetDateTime odtParsed2 = OffsetDateTime.parse(date2, dtf);
    OffsetDateTime odtParsed3 = OffsetDateTime.parse(date3, dtf);
    OffsetDateTime odtParsed4 = OffsetDateTime.parse(date4, dtf);
    OffsetDateTime odtParsed5 = OffsetDateTime.parse(date5, dtf);
    // print it
    System.out.println("Parsed OffsetDateTime is " + odtParsed);
    System.out.println("Parsed OffsetDateTime is " + odtParsed1);
    System.out.println("Parsed OffsetDateTime is " + odtParsed2);
    System.out.println("Parsed OffsetDateTime is " + odtParsed3);
    System.out.println("Parsed OffsetDateTime is " + odtParsed4);
    System.out.println("Parsed OffsetDateTime is " + odtParsed5);
}
```

Output:

```
Parsed OffsetDateTime is 2021-04-23T12:09:56.123-07:00
Parsed OffsetDateTime is 2021-04-23T12:09:56.123+02:00
Parsed OffsetDateTime is 2021-04-23T12:09:56.123Z
Parsed OffsetDateTime is 2021-04-23T12:09:56-07:00
Parsed OffsetDateTime is 2021-04-23T12:09:56+02:00
Parsed OffsetDateTime is 2021-04-23T12:09:56Z
```

and if you don't want an offset of zero hours and zero minutes to be output as a `Z`, then use the `DateTimeFormatter` for output like this:

```java
OffsetDateTime odtParsed5 = OffsetDateTime.parse(date5, dtf);
```

which makes the output look like this:

```
Parsed OffsetDateTime is 2021-04-23T12:09:56.000+00:00
```

Where the millis of day are printed even if they are all zero.

## Another Edit:

To check if the date is in the range **30 days in the past** to **30 days in the future** it might be good to use the date parts only:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // the first part is already known from the examples above...
    String date = "2021-04-23T12:09:56.123-07:00";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]xxx");
    OffsetDateTime odtParsed = OffsetDateTime.parse(date, dtf);
    
    // get the current instant as an OffsetDateTime (in UTC == +00:00)
    OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    
    /*
     * might be smart to keep time of day out of the calculation, so...
     */
    
    // get the date only out of the OffsetDateTime
    LocalDate today = now.toLocalDate();
    // create one for 30 days before
    LocalDate thirtyDaysBeforeToday = today.minusDays(30);
    // and one 30 days in the future
    LocalDate thirtyDaysInTheFuture = today.plusDays(30);
    // finally extract the date part from the parsed date time
    LocalDate d = odtParsed.toLocalDate();
    
    // make your checks using the LocalDates, maybe separate the two cases of an invalid date
    if (d.isBefore(thirtyDaysBeforeToday)) {
        System.err.println("Invalid date: too far in the past");
    } else if (d.isAfter(thirtyDaysInTheFuture)) {
        System.err.println("Invalid date: too far in the future");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Valid date");
    }
}
```

Try some different valid and invalid dates...

Comment: But -7 was just an example it must be compatible with any date provided. Please can you suggest how can I make it generic.

Comment: @NikitaDixit sure, see the last edit of my answer.

Comment: Hi thanks yes it was more than enough. I appreciate all your help but parsing is perfect I also want to check if the date given is not in the past or 30 days from today. Basically I need to check if the date is valid or not. It should be either today's date or within 30 days in future. I am not able to pass those test/ checks.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you kindly advise as to how can I fetch current time i.e. now using offset.

Comment: @NikitaDixit you're welcome... Please consider accepting one of the answers. Accepting an answer even grants you a little amount of reputation.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 separate problems here:

1. `±hh:mm` - as per the [docs of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (remember, reading is fundamental! Always read the javadoc *before* asking SO questions!), `±` isn't a thing. `hh` and `mm` are things, but not 'offset hours'. The 'pattern' that represents tz offsets is a single letter; you're most likely looking for `Z`. But that doesn't ordinarily include the `:`.
2. `LocalDateTime` cannot represent offsets and doesn't know about timezones. If you want that, you're looking for either `ZonedDateTime` or most likely `OffsetDateTime`.
3. Your pattern doesn't include a locale which means the output of it, and what it can parse, depends on the locale of the computer you run this code on, which sounds bad. Always use `.ofPattern("someString", Locale.ENGLISH)` (or some other locale) unless you are really *really* sure you want the app to depend on the configuration of the server you run it on, which should be very rare.

Comment: While remembering to supply a locale is a good habit (and `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` is this is what is desired), in this case leaving it out hasn’t got any practical implications since the pattern does not include any parts that depend on locale.

Answer (score 1):

Your documentation uses ± to mean either `+` or `-`, and its placeholders aren't the Java ones. Just use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`.